# Arithmetic Progression, Tn and Tm proving sum

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

How can I prove this?

If in an A.P., Tm=n, Tn=m, prove d=-1.

Comment: What are Tm, Tn, n, m, d? Providing context helps people answer your question

Comment: In arithmetic progression, there are sequences, in which first number is referred as a or T1, second is T2, third is T3 and so on..., there is one formula called Tn=a+(n-1)d , and second one is Sn=n/2[2a+(n-1)d], these are for those who are studying in class 10

Comment: Then add this to your question, for those people who don't know what they mean. Also, not everyone knows what 'class 10' is (I certainly don't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume it is given that $m\ne n$.

You have $T(m)=n$ and $T(n)=m$. So,

$$a+(m-1)d=n\quad \text{and} \quad a+(n-1)d=m$$

Hint: Subtract the two equalities.

Comment: I came up to a+nd-d=a+md-d what to do next?

Comment: I think you have made a mistake. $a+nd-d=m$ and $a+md-d=n$. They are not equal.

Comment: Subtract them. You will have $(a+nd-d)-(a+md-d)=m-n$.

Comment: OK, SO NOW I'VE GOT m-n=(n-m)d what about next? Should I have to pplut values of m and n or something else?

Comment: Since $n-m\ne0$, you can divide both sides by $n-m$.

Comment: what have you written and why are the dollar signs

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Mathjax. Try to read the post on computer.

Comment: Ok, so after dividing both sides by n-m I've got this    m-n/n-m=d

Comment: And that is $-1$ on L.H.S.

Comment: And that's my question why m-n/n-m is equal to - 1?

Comment: $(-1)(n-m)=-n+m=m-n$.

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding the imprecision of the question, and assuming $m\neq n$:

The slope is $\frac{T_m-m}{T_n-n}=\frac{n-m}{m-n}=-1$

Answer (score 0):

we have

$(T_i) $ arithmetic sequence

$$\implies T_n=T_m+(n-m)d $$

$$\implies m-n=(n-m)d $$

$$\implies (d+1)(n-m )=0$$

$$\implies d=-1$$